# Der Unterschied zwischen »hierher«, »her« und »hierhin«

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

> Ich bin hergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen.
>   Ich bin hierhergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen.
>   Ich bin hinhergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen.

I have come here to learn a lot of German.

Kann man in diesem Kontext auch *hierhin* verwenden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du unterstellst drei trennbare Verben, von denen nur eines existiert.

*Herkommen* bedeutet *an diesen Ort kommen*.

> Ich bin *hergekommen*, um viel Deutsch zu lernen

Ist ein völlig valider Satz.

Alle anderen Sätze würden das Verb *kommen* benutzen. Der Ort, *wohin* gekommen wird, wird dann durch ein Adverbial des Ortes klargestellt.

> Ich bin *hierher gekommen*, um mehr über Deutsch zu lernen.
> Nicht: <strike>hierhergekommen</strike>

Ein zusammengesetztes Verb *hierherkommen* existiert nicht. Es handelt sich um zwei verschiedene Wörter.

*Hinher* existiert überhaupt nicht, weder in Kombination mit einem Verb noch sonst. Demnach ist dein dritter Vorschlag falsch.

*Hierhin* ist allerdings wieder möglich, es wäre analog zu *hierher*.

> Ich werde *hierhin kommen*, um noch viel mehr Deutsch zu lernen.

Allerdings ist es etwas seltsam, von *hierhin* zu reden; denn *hin* beschreibt in der Regel eine Bewegung auf etwas *hin*, während man den Ort *hier* in der Regel schon betreten hat und nur von woanders *herkommen* kann.

---

Anmerkung: Nachdem ich Huberts Antwort gelesen habe, fällt mir auf, dass ich noch einen Satz über *hinkommen* verlieren sollte. Das Verb existiert auch, in einer ähnlichen Bedeutung wie *herkommen*. Der Unterschied: Bei *hinkommen* ist es eine Bewegung vom Sprecher weg (oder ganz woanders hin), während *herkommen* immer eine Bewegung auf den Sprecher zu ist. Möglich ist also auch:

> Ich bin *dort hingekommen*, um Deutsch zu lernen.

(*hier* funktioniert nicht, denn *hier* ist der Sprecher.)

Answer (score 5):

### hin und her

Das Wort bzw. die Silbe »her« kennzeichnet eine Bewegung, die beim Sprecher endet:

> Oh, das freut mich, dass du endlich zu mir **her**gekommen bist.
>   Kannst du mir bitte die Zeitung **her**bringen?
>   Macht hier mal ein bisschen sauber! In einer Stunde kommt der Direktor zu uns **her**.

Das Wort bzw. die Silbe »hin« kennzeichnet eine Bewegung, die irgendwo anders, also nicht beim Sprecher endet:

> Zu diesem Gipfel führt anscheinend kein Weg **hin**. Wie sollen wir da **hin**kommen?
>   Kannst du bitte die Zeitung zu dem Herrn dort an der Theke **hin**bringen?
>   Wo gehst du **hin**?

---

### hinkommen und herkommen

Es gibt die zusammengesetzten und teilbaren Verben »*hinkommen*« und »*herkommen*«, die beide eine Ortsveränderung ausdrücken:

> 1. Ich bin **hergekommen**, um Deutsch zu lernen.
>      Ich **komme her**, um Deutsch zu lernen.
> 2. Die Schule ist im Nachbarort. Ich bin dort **hingekommen**, um Deutsch zu lernen.
>      Ich **komme hin**, um Deutsch zu lernen.

(1) bedeutet, dass sich der Sprecher dort aufhält, wo er Deutsch lernt.
(2) bedeutet, dass der Spreche nicht an der Stelle ist, wo er Deutsch lernt; aber er spricht von diesem entfernten Ort.

---

### hierhin und hierher

Zwei andere Zusammensetzungen mit *hin* und *her* sind *hierhin* und *hierher*. Dabei ist »*hierhin*« streng genommen eigentlich ein Oxymoron, denn »hier« bezeichnet die Stelle, an der sich der Sprecher befindet, und »hin« bezeichnet eine Bewegung, die überall sonst, nur eben nicht *hier* enden kann.

Aufgelöst wird dieser Widerspruch dadurch, dass »*hier*« in großen Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums gar nicht nur den Ort des Sprechers bezeichnet, sondern dass dieses Wort auch einen beliebigen anderen Ort bezeichnen kann. So wird z.B. in Österreich wesentlich strenger zwischen »hier« und »dort« unterschieden als in weiten Teilen Deutschlands. Daher wird »hierhin« in Österreich auch seltener verwendet als in Deutschland.

Mit diesen beiden Worten lassen sich diese Sätze bilden:

> Siehst du die leere Stelle zwischen Tür und Fenster? Genau **hierhin** möchte ich eine Vase stellen.
>
> Bitte sage Günter, er soll die Kiste **hierher**, in dieses Zimmer, tragen.

---

### hier + hin/her + kommen

Interessant wird es nun, wenn die beiden oben beschriebenen Möglichkeiten zusammentreffen, wenn man also *hier + her + kommen* schreiben will. In diesem Fall sind sowohl »hierher kommen« als auch »hier herkommen« möglich, dasselbe gilt auch für *hin*:

> 1. Ich werde morgen nochmals **hierher kommen**.
> 2. Ich werde morgen nochmals **hier herkommen**.
> 3. Ich werde morgen nochmals **hierhin kommen**.
> 4. Ich werde morgen nochmals **hier hinkommen**.
> 5. <del>Ich werde morgen nochmals **hier kommen**.</del> (falsch!)

Die Sätze haben geringfügig unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, ich beginne aber gleich mit dem letzten, der weder *hin* noch *her* enthält:

Das Wort »kommen« hat neben der Bedeutung »einem Ort erreichen« (a) umgangssprachlich auch noch die Bedeutung »einen Orgasmus haben« (b). Wesentlich ist dabei, dass die Bedeutung (a) immer mit einer Ortsveränderung verbunden ist, während (b) an einem festen Ort stattfindet.

Üblicherweise gibt der Kontext klar vor, ob mit kommen (a) oder (b) gemeint ist, aber wenn in einem Satz ein statischer Ort (»*hier*«) genannt wird, ohne dass gleichzeitig eine Ortsveränderung (»*hin*« oder »*her*«) ausgedrückt wird, ist die Interpretation als (a) nur mehr möglich, wenn man dem Sprecher einen Grammatikfehler unterstellt.

Da zumindest beim männlichen Orgasmus mit der Ejakulation ebenfalls eine Bewegung stattfindet, lassen die Varianten

- hierher kommen
- hierhin kommen

ebenfalls die Interpretation (b) zu. Das kann ausgeschlossen werden, indem man die beiden anderen Variaten wählt:

- hier herkommen
- hier hinkommen

Denn *herkommen* und *hinkommen* sind zwei Verben, die beide eine Ortsveränderung bedeuten und nicht mehr anders interpretiert werden können, eben weil hier die Silben »hin« und »her« schon im Wort enthalten sind.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be confusion about the purposes of *hin* and *her*.
*Her* is used for movements that end in the speaker's location; *hin* is used for movements that end elsewhere. German for *to and fro* is *hin und her*. (*Back and forth* translates to *hin und zurück*.)

*Hin* is straightforward in that when you add a location such as *hier* or *da*, it always defines the destination of the movement. (*Hierhin* is used for destinations close to the speaker but different from the speaker. "Komm hierhin!" is accompanied by pointing to the location; "Komm [hier]her!" usually is not.) But in *daher*, *da* usually defines the origin because the destination is already known to be the speaker, hence cannot be 'da'. In other words, *daher* is short for *von da her*. (It can, however, be used analogously to *hierhin*, i.e. in connection with pointing to a nearby location that is the destination.)

The sentence "Ich bin hinhergekommen" has a precise literal translation covering all its weirdness and falseness and most of its connotations: "I have come tofro."

It follows from all this that *hierher* is normally just a more explicit version of plain *her*. 'Normally' because *hier* is normally evaluated relative to the speaker, whereas *her* is usually evaluated according to context. E.g., it can be relative to the recipient ("Du willst, dass ich herkomme").

"Ich bin hierhin gekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen" is a grammatical sentence but would only make sense in an unlikely context such as the following: I came to *this* desk (the one I am pointing to, not the one where I am sitting) to learn a lot of German. Now I am sitting here, at the desk next to it, and learning French instead.

(This interpretation only works because in today's colloquial German, the composite past can almost always replace the simple past. In English it cannot, so I had to switch for the translation.)

Comment: You wrote: »*Hin* is used for movements that end in the speaker's location; *her* is used for movements that end elsewhere.« This would mean: »Komm bitte zu mir *hin*« and »Heute fahren wir zu Onkel Herbert *her*«. This is wrong! The exact opposite is correct!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I fixed the problem by swapping *hin* and *her* in the single (I think) sentence which contained the error. You are invited to fix such trivial but (for non-native speakers) confusing mistakes immediately when you see them in any of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

Meiner Meinung nach geht es nur mit "hin", denn "her" bedeutet, in die Richtung des Sprechers. Der Sprecher kann ja nicht auf sich selbst zugehen, deshalb sagt man "hinkommen" und das heißt: an einen bestimmten Ort und nicht zum Sprecher selbst kommen.

Ich bin hier hingekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen.

Ich glaube, das "her" wird ähnlich oft verwendet wie das "raus" und anstelle der richtigen Präposition "hinaus". Wir sagen heutzutage eher "einen Brief rausschicken" als "hinausschicken" und eher "her" als "hin", denn es hört sich umständlicher an und der Sprachwandel umgeht diese Umständlichkeit.

Laut Duden ist auch nur die Zusammenschreibung von hierher + kommen möglich.
Und damit sagt der Sprecher etwas zu jemandem, der zum Sprecher gekommen ist.

Bist du hierhergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Gibt es für diese Meinung zufällig auch Argumente von z.B. Wörterbüchern o.ä., die das auch so sehen - und sich verlinken lassen? Denn wenn ich sage "ich bin hierher gekommen, um xy zu tun" - dann beziehe ich mich auf den Ort, an dem ich stehe. Hierher bin ich von außen rein gekommen und bin nun hier. - das ist demnach falsch? Ansonsten finde ich das Duden-Argument steht entgegen der geäußerten eigenen Meinung, denn das Duden-Argument scheint mein Beispiel zu bestätigen.