# Ist es stilistisch korrekt zu sagen, dass man »viel Deutsch lernt«?

Tags: style

In einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25829/der-unterschied-zwischen-hierher-her-und-hierhin) kam dieser Satz vor:

> Ich bin hergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen.

Man kann ohne Zweifel *viel Milch* trinken, *viel Sand* ausstreuen, *viel Honig* aufs Brot schmieren, und auch sonst viel von diversen Singulariatantum konsumieren, verarbeiten, usw. Aber bei Sprachen bin ich mir unsicher, ob es stilistisch gutes Deutsch ist, das Wort »*viel*« voranzustellen.

Man kann *viel lernen*, und man kann *Deutsch lernen*. Man kann auch *gut* oder *schlecht* Deutsch sprechen. Auch mit »sie beherrscht nur wenig Deutsch« und »er spricht ein wenig Deutsch« habe ich keine Probleme. Aber *viel + Deutsch* will mir nicht gefallen.

Grammatisch scheint nichts dagegen zu sprechen, aber ist das dem Stil nach gutes Deutsch, wenn man sagt, dass man »viel Deutsch lernt«?

Comment: Der einzige Manko in dem Satz ist "Ich bin hergekommen". Das klingt hier komisch. Ich sehe aber keine Einwände dafür, viel Deutsch zu lernen.

Comment: @Em1: Du schreibst: »Das klingt hier komisch.« Wo ist dieses *hier*? Denn hier (im Osten Österreichs) klingt das ganz normal und wird keineswegs als Manko empfunden.

Comment: Mit "hier" hatte ich mich eigentlich auf den Kontext bezogen. Natürlich fehlt der wirkliche Kontext, also ist German StackExchange gemeint gewesen, oder ein VHS-Kurs. Aber als losgelöster Satz und dem Zusammenhang, den ich herausinterpretiere, klingt es für mich einfach schräg, dies mit "Ich bin hergekommen" einzuleiten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Satz ist in Ordnung, da man das *viel* statt auf *Deutsch* auf *Deutsch lernen* beziehen kann.

> Ich bin ins Trainingslager gefahren, um viel zu laufen.

Answer (score 3):

Aus dem Kontext gerissen klingt der Satz *Ich bin hergekommen, um viel Deutsch zu lernen* (für mich als Hamburger) sprachlich nicht schön.

Das liegt vielleicht daran, dass man zwar viele Sprachen lernen kann, wir die Einteilung von Sprachen in viel und wenig aber nicht gewohnt sind.
Der Satz *Er spricht wenig Deutsch* würde mir nicht auffallen.
In einer Situation, in der jemand in ein deutschsprachiges Land zieht, um die deutsche Sprache zu erlernen, ist die Aussage jedoch nicht falsch, und man kann es so ausdrücken.

Der Klang des Satzes ändert sich, wenn man ein weiteres Wort, beispielsweise *möglichst* hinzufügt.

> Ich bin komme aus Italien, mache aber gerade ein Praktikum in
>   Hannover, und hoffe, dort möglichst viel Deutsch zu lernen.

Hilfreich ist auch, sich dies anhand anderer Beispiele zu verdeutlichen:

Formuliert man den Satz *Er hat in kurzer Zeit viel Deutsch gelernt* in *Er hat in kurzer Zeit viel der deutschen Sprache gelernt* um, verliert er für mich seinen unbeholfenen Klang.

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist die Ausdrucksweise völlig in Ordnung. Sprachenlernen hat ja auch einen quantitativen Aspekt in Bezug auf den Wortschatz.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde die Formulierung (ebenfalls) unglücklich, weil unklar bleibt, was eigentlich *viel* ist und außer Frage steht, dass es sich hier um eine schlecht (oder gar nicht) messbare Größe handelt.

Mögliche Alternativen:

- Ich verwende viel Zeit auf das Erlernen von Deutsch
- Ich lerne viele Vokabeln, erweitere meinen Wortschatz
- Ich setze mich intensiv mit Grammatik auseinander
- Ich arbeite konzentriert an meiner Aussprache

Comment: Wenn offen bleibt, was viel ist, so ist dies immer gegeben. Wenn Hubert in seiner Frage sagt, man trinkt viel Milch oder man schmiert viel Honig auf's Brot, ist die Aussage in irgendeiner Form aussagekräftig? Für manch einen ist 1 Liter Milch am Tag viel, ein Freund von mir trinkt aber schon zum Frühstück soviel, ich würd behaupten, er trinkt zu viel Milch.

Comment: @Em1: Aber in diesen Fällen ist nur die Menge diskutierbar (wie viel ist *viel*), dass es sich um Milch oder Honig handelt, ist klar. Bei einem Objekt wie "Deutsch" ist nicht einmal das klar, deswegen bleibe ich dabei, dass in diesem Zusammenhang *viel* noch weniger aussagt.

Comment: Im Fall von »Deutsch« ist meiner Meinung nach - ganz analog wie bei der Milch - durchaus klar worum es sich handelt: Nämlich um »Deutsch«. Das Argument, das Wort »viel« sage bei *Deutsch* weniger aus als bei *Milch* kann ich überhaupt nicht nachvollziehen.